# mongodb insert really slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, insert

i use mongodb to manage device log datas. Right now, it has over one million documents. the document contains more than 30 fields which combine with embed fields. Now, it's really slow when i insert new documents. The insert cost more than 1000ms. From the slow query ops, i get the logs like this:

```
{
    "op" : "insert",
    "ns" : "xxx.LogDeviceReport",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
        "deviceId" : ObjectId("xxxx"),
        "en" : "xxxxxx",
        "status" : 1,
        'other fields, more than 30 fields...'
        ...
        ...

    },
    "ninserted" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "writeConflicts" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        },
        "MMAPV1Journal" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount" : {
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "W" : NumberLong(1477481)
            }
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "millis" : 977,
    "execStats" : {

    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2016-08-02T22:01:01.270Z"),
    "client" : "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
    "allUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "xxx",
            "db" : "xxx"
        }
    ],
    "user" : "xx@xx"
}
```

I checked the index, like this:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "xxx.LogDeviceReport"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "time" : 1
        },
        "name" : "time_1",
        "ns" : "xxx.LogDeviceReport",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 604800,
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Only an _id index and a ttl index by time, no any other indexes.

I guess the 'query' slow the operate. In mongodb doc, it tells that only the _id will be checked the unique, but in the logs, all fields in the 'query', does it matter?

if not this reason, what makes it so slow? Can any one help me ?

Comment: 30 fields seems like an awful lot. Likely besides the question, but you should probably add more tables and reduce the information between the tables.

Comment: How many indexes are on the collection? How large are the indexes relative to the available RAM? Each index will need to be updated for each insert operation; a large number of indexes will increase the expense of each insert on the collection.

Comment: ... and as an addendum to Adam's question: how many of these indexes are declared unique?

Comment: there were only tow indexes, one is _id, one is the time by ttl

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mongodb 3+ you can consider using **WiredTiger** as storage engine than **MMAPV1** which is being used in your case.

I have personally saw a 4x improvement when I have inserted up to 156000 documents in a single go.

MMAPV1 took around 40 min and when I switched to WiredTiger same task was completed in 10 min.

Please check this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/whats-new-mongodb-30-part-3-performance-efficiency-gains-new-storage-architecture) from MongoDB blog for more information

Note :: This is only from **MongoDB 3.0 +**

Comment: The link I sent claims improvement in the range of 7x to 10x , but any improvement is an improvement

Comment: Not yet. the db is in prodoct env, the boss do not want to switch with no test.  Now, another group will use another mongo instance. They will use the WiredTiger. If it works, i would switch this one too. Thanks for u idea!

Comment: @hudao Any Luck with other team implementation

Comment: from 40 minutes to 10 minutes is an improvement of 4 times not 400 times as stated in the answer